# Need a linux distro with Linux 3.14.17 (vanilla)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I need to compile my code on Linux 3.14.17 (vanilla) kernel.
Can anyone help me find a distro which comes with this kernel by default.
If there is no distro which comes with this kernel then how can I use this kernel or which Linux distro is based on the above kernel.

Thanks
Kumar

Comment: Why do you ask? The precise kernel version has little importance to compile a user-space application... (but kernel versions matter for kernel modules). The libc version is more important for user-space code.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch this can matter, if you need a newly provided kernel API.

Comment: In that case, a newer kernel (e.g. some 3.15) probably will still provide that kernel API.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to use your favorite distro (for example Ubuntu) and to compile the kernel at the desired version.

On this [link](http://mapopa.blogspot.fr/2009/01/compiling-2.html), there is a step-by-step explanation on how to compile a **vanilla** kernel for Ubuntu.
Adapt for the given version you want.

Comment: Okay thanks for reply. Just one more question as vanilla kernel is most basic kernel and ubuntu use chocolate kernel which has GUI support, will over writing the ubuntu kernel cause any problem ?

Comment: Why do you think that Ubuntu kernel has "GUI support"? What does it mean to you? The `Xorg` server is not in the kernel!

Comment: Nop. When you do the command `fakeroot make-kpkg --initrd --append-to-version=-vanillaice kernel_image kernel_headers`, you can change `-vanillaice` by what you want and it will create a new kernel. It is the name which is important. Moreover, there is a security when you install the package telling you if you overwrite a kernel.

Comment: Notice that `make-kpkg` is producing `*.deb` kernel packages. When they are installed with `dpkg -i` the `grub` configuration is updated automatically.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch> True, I forgot. I edited my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu provides special repository with packaged kernels for alomost every upstream version. This [folder](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14.17-utopic/) provides kernel packages for 3.14.17. Just download and install them them via

```
dpkg -i *.deb
```

Check your architecture i.e. i386 or amd64 before downloading.